# Accessing items in a referenced project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

When a C# project references another C# project (e.g. a lib), Visual Studio adds something like this to the project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\some\path\lib.csproj">
    <Project>{4beb6b28-90f5-77c3-af2a-f5fa3336dac9}</Project>
    <Name>Lib</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Let’s assume, `lib.csproj` contains some items like this:

```
<SpecialFile Include="foo.dll" />
<SpecialFile Inclued="bar.txt" />
```

How can I access these `SpecialFile` items in the first project file? I’d like to do something like this:

```
<Target Name="SpecialFileCopyTarget" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <Copy
      DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"
      SourceFiles="@(SpecialFile)"         <-- ?????
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

I think I do not want to `Import` the `lib.csproj`, just get the items somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlPeek task allows to query any XML file:

```
<XmlPeek Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='n' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;"
         XmlInputPath="%(ProjectReference.FullPath)"
         Query="/n:Project/n:ItemGroup/n:SpecialFile/@Include">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="SpecialFiles" />
</XmlPeek>
```

This code will collect SpecialFile items from all referenced projects. Please specify ToolsVersion="4.0" for your project.